# How are multi-shader renderers usually handled in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, software-design

Let's say I have some Renderer in my engine and I want it to be able to render some meshes. Each of these meshes might want to be rendered with a different shader: one needs Phong, another one needs PBR, another one might be cell-shaded...
This means I would need a PhongMaterial with ambient, diffuse, specular, and a PBRMaterial with albedo, metallic... Basically a different type of material for every type of shader (unless I use some ubermaterial with vague attribute names like "texture0", "texture1"...)

So instead of passing the Shader as a parameter to the Renderer, it might just be better to make a PhongRenderer and a PBRRenderer and many more, one for every shader/material type. Is this any similar to how things are usually done in OpenGL projects? Are particle system renderers handled this way?

Answer (score 2):

Well, think about it this way: OpenGL only deals with drawing points, lines or triangles, one at a time, submitted in batches. The way this drawing happens is controlled by a state machine. And one of the state vector elements is the shader program used.

It's perfectly normal – even expected – when using OpenGL to switch state several times when rendering a frame; also shaders between drawing calls.

However switching shaders may impose some heavy overhead; especially with early programmable GPUs and their early drivers. Which is why übershaders came to be, so that more geometry could be dispatched with a single draw call, yet support multiple materials. But with the current generation of GPUs (as of writing this in early 2022) thanks to GPU device generated commands this has been alleviated. I.e. one submits a larger geometry batch, which is device side into commands that switch the shader and issue the draw calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very informative. However, I think my question was wrongly put. What I was wondering is how multi-shader renderers are usually handled in a OpenGL software project, not by the driver or the API. I guess it was more of a software architecture kind of question, how to organize the various parts of the code, be them classes, structs or free functions. I know there isn't just ONE valid answer but I always end up finding drawbacks every time I've got an implementation idea. Thank you again for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

as you said in your comment, there is no clear answer.

most projects use at least dozens if not hundreds of shaders depending on the project and how they are organized depends on the project.

to answer your example, as you may know Phong, PBR and cell-shading requires completely different setup and I would have separate rendering function for each. at least you may reuse vertices and indices but I think that's the only thing you can share between those 3 completely different kind of rendering.

it would make sense to have a rendering function that takes a shader as input for slightly different shaders. for example, Phong with single light and multiple lights. Even this requires careful implementation as each shaders requires different uniforms or other kind of setups.